# Google Apps Script [createServerClickHandler]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a GUI where user enters homework for the day. On submit, form will send data to Calendar and Spreadsheet.

Apps Script is telling me that 'createServerClickHandler' is deprecated. What other alternatives are there?

Is there anything wrong with my codes?

```
//Create the GUI form

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Form and Calendar Events');

  //Create a penel which holds all the form elelemnts
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');

  //Create the form elelemnts
  var startDateLabel = app.createLabel('Homework Start Date:');
  var startDate = app.createDateBox().setId('startDate');

  var endDateLabel = app.createLabel('Homework End Date:');
  var endDate = app.createDateBox().setId('endDate');

  var hwTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Homework title:');
  var hwTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('hwTitle').setId('hwTitle');

  var hwDetailLabel = app.createLabel('Homework Details:');
  var hwDetails = app.createTextArea()
      .setSize('200', '100').setId('hwDetail').setName('hwDetail');
  var btn = app.createButton('Submit Homework');

  //Create handler which will execute 'Submit Homework(e)' on clicking the button
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('Submit Homework');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  //Add this handler to the button
  btn.addClickHandler(handler);

  //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
  panel.add(startDateLabel)
  .add(startDate)

  .add(endDateLabel)
  .add(endDate)

  .add(hwTitleLabel)
  .add(hwTitle)

  .add(hwDetailLabel)
  .add(hwDetails)

  .add(btn);
  //Add this panel to the application
  app.add(panel);
  //return the application
  return app;
}

function createEvents(e){

  //Get the active application
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  try{
    //get the entries;
    var startDate = e.parameter.startDate;
    var endDate = e.parameter.endDate;
    var hwTitle = e.parameter.hwTitle;
    var hwDetails = e.parameter.hwDetails;

    //Get the calendar
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Paul Lim')[0];//Change the calendar name
    var startDate = startDate;
    var endDate = endDate;
    //Create the events
    cal.createEvent(hwTitle, startDate, endDate,{description:hwDetail});

    //Log the entries in a spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PTSsvjsvb-UVuJ_z9WoLGVZ01YigjLQ5nCi7ujU4Gek');//Change the spreadhseet key to yours
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[new Date(), endDate, hwTitle, hwDetails]]);

    //Show the confirmation message
    app.add(app.createLabel('Homework created successfully'));
    //make the form panel invisible
    app.getElementById('panel').setVisible(false);
    return app;
  }

  //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
  catch(e){
    app.add(app.createLabel('Error occurred: '+e));
    return app;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `createServerHandler` instead... to avoid this kind of problems I'd suggest you use the autocomplete feature in the script editor:  if you type "create" and hit control-space you'll see all the available methods, including the deprecated ones being stroked through.

There is also another issue in your code:  you forgot to set names to your date Widgets, they won't return any value in the server handler function.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.

I changed it to the following


`//Create handler which will execute 'Submit(e)' on clicking the button
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('Submit');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  //Add this handler to the button
  btn.addClickHandler(handler);`

However, it says 'Script function not found: Submit'.

Comment: the function name in your script is "createEvents", use that as argument in createServerHandler.